# Fasten ceiling panel so that it is removable

Tags: ceiling

I am making some fabric ceiling panels. The panels are wooden stretchers with fabric stapled to them, similar to a painting canvas.

The panels will be flush mounted with trim boards that border them. The panels are different sizes, but about 4' x 6' or so. The problem is how to mount them so that they can be removed if needed to access various utilities in the ceiling.

It is not possible to shift the panels side to side, because they are hard up against the trim boards. Also, they cannot be pushed upwards because there are joists right above them.

So, one idea is to use magnets and another is some kind of spear and socket connector, kind of like a speaker cover. Both of these approaches have the disadvantage that it will be difficult to pry the panels out, because there is no gap between the edge of the panels and the trim board.

Comment: Magswitch® magnets.  OR just use strong magnets  or spear and socket and **sew a loop** of matching fabric on the corners and use it pull the panel down.

Comment: Will they cover any lights or junction boxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mount removable panels with Velcro. I purchase the self adhesive type if it won’t stick I staple it 4 small pieces will hold a fair size piece of plywood and your drain pieces sound very light weight.

Answer (score 0):

I've considered similar and settled on the following: MAGNETS AND SCREWS

In each corner use a good quality neodymium magnet with a countersink hole. Don't use the cheap ones including many found on Azm as they are too thin (break easy) and the screw hole is often some very small size. [Here is an example of a better quality one](https://www.magnet4less.com/neodymium-magnets-3-4-in-x-3-4-in-x-1-8-in-countersunk-hole-8).

Attach the magnet either the panel or the ceiling. Then use a screw or small bolt for the other side. Screw it in or out to adjust the 'height' to get the panels to flush up nice and flat with your frame or adjacent panel.

Yes, taking apart is a not easy, but the connection is hidden. To take apart use a small Allen wrench, slim enough to fit the gap, then turn 90 degrees to get the hook part on the back side of the panel and gently pull it free

[image]